# People to re-arrange so that neighbors changed

Tags: permutations

In how many ways 20 people be re arrange so that everyone had a different right hand neighbour in new arrangement

Comment: $18795307255050944540$

Comment: What have you attempted?  Have you worked out the first few cases?  For small $n$$, using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle is an option.  However, the best approach is to construct a recurrence relation.